# Django generic DeleteView authentication

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

I want to create a post that only the author and the authorized groups can delete.

```
class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
   model = Posts
   template_name = 'deletepost.html'
   success_url = '/home'
```

Currently all users can delete posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PermissionRequiredMixin` - see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin).

For example:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

...

class PostDeleteView(PermissionRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Posts
    template_name = 'deletepost.html'
    success_url = '/home'
    permission_required = 'myapp.delete_posts'  # <---- set your permissions here (str or tuple)

    def has_permission(self):
        has_perms = super().has_permission()
        # You can check if self.request.user is the author here
        self.object = self.get_object()
        user_is_author = self.object.author == self.request.user  # example only
        return has_perms or user_is_author
```